# Arduino clear buffer

Tags: c++, c, arduino, microprocessors

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LED 13

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() == 4) {
    char command[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) command[i] = Serial.read();
    command[4] = '\0';

    Serial.println(command);

    if (strcmp(command, "AAAA") == 0) {
      digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
      Serial.println("LED13 is ON");
    } else if (strcmp(command, "BBBB") == 0) {
      digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
      Serial.println("LED13 is OFF");
    }
  }
}
```

I have that code, that reads 4 characters long strings. However, I need it to ignore any string that is not 4 characters long.

So, imagine this input:

```
AAAA
BBBB
BBB
AAAA
```

Right now, it reads {"AAAA", "BBBB", "BBBA"}.

I need it to read {"AAAA", "BBBB", "AAAA"}.

Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the duration time of inter-character delay. Set a timeout, such as 100ms. When there is no more data received after the specified timeout, that means the whole string is transferred completely. Then you can check the length of the string and execute your application logic.